# Hide metric from tflearn fit?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tflearn

Write show_metric=False and snapshot_epoch=False

```
currentnetwork.model.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain, n_epoch=self['n_epoch'], shuffle=True, validation_set=(Xtest, Ytest),
          show_metric=False,
          snapshot_epoch=False,
        )
```

But still get in output

```
> Training Step: 7  | total loss: 2.90061 | time: 7.083s | Adam | epoch:
> 007 | loss: 2.90061 -- iter: 40/40
```